# Finding longest length of filename using wc and assigning variable

Tags: bash, unix

```
cd subdir1/subdir2

ineedthis=$(find subdir3/ -name "*.csv" | tr ' ' '_') ## assigning name of the file into this variable
echo -n $ineedthis | wc -c
```

I wanted to see the length of all the filename by assigning a variable called ineedthis and making changes such that I don't have any spaces between the names. Then, I tried to use echo -n to read the name only and count the characters to find the length of the name. However, when I try to use wc -c on the echo statement, it would give me the number of characters of the chunk, instead of giving me the length of each filename.

What I was hoping was:

```
# numbers indicating the length of filename

9 subdir3/saying/hello.csv
6 subdir3/saying/hi.csv
9 subdir3/nay/noway.csv
12 subdir3/nay/nomethod.csv
16 subdir3/nay/you_dont_say.csv
```

Comment: Here is fully explained. Try this:
https://askubuntu.com/a/930935

Comment: I was hoping not to use awk as I am still unfamiliar with this.

Comment: Sorry. Wrong formatting. I was trying to say subdir3/saying/hi.csv, which means I am just interested in length of filename, which is "hi.csv"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find subdir3/ -name "*.csv" |\
while read path; do
    $file=$(basename "$path")
    $len=$(echo -n "$file" | wc -c) 
    echo $len "$path"
done
```

- `while` loops over each path found by `find`
- `basename` strips off everything up to final `/` (optionally a suffix can also be removed. bash provides bultins like `${path##*/}` and `${path%%.csv}` that are similar)

Comment: Thank you! This helps a lot.

Comment: Can I still sort the length (by longest to shortest) and extract the head?